# Run a second command after the first completes or errors

Tags: windows, command-line

I know that you can run two commands in sequence, with one line, by putting `&&` between them like this:

```
hostname && w32tm /query /configuration
```

However, this `&&` function has a limitation:  It only executes the second command if the first is successful.

My preferred use for `&&` is to run informational commands directly from Start->Run (or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) without having to type them into the CMD window or worry about the CMD console exiting prematurely.  For example:

```
cmd /c hostname && w32tm /query /configuration && pause
```

Due to the aforementioned limitation though, this command will automatically exit the console window if w32tm fails - i.e.: If the Windows Time service is not running.

Is there a similar operator I can use to string commands together on one line, which will allow the second command to run even if the first errors out?

I'm looking for this to be compatible from Windows XP upward.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just use `&` instead of `&&`. The second command will be executed even if the first one fails.

Comment: Here is the documentation for it: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: what if I want `command2` to be executed only when `command1` fails? (XOR)

Comment: Then use `command1 || command2`